# Deleting Core Data record from Detail View of SplitView Controller

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to delete a CoreData record directly from the Detail View of the SplitViewController.

This is what I've tried:

```
[self.detailItem.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.detailItem];
```

But it only deletes it from the TableView. When I restart the app the record is still there.
How can I delete it properly? Thank you!

Comment: Do you *save* the managed object context?

Comment: Rookie mistake. That pretty much solved it, thanks. If you want you can post it as an answer so I'll approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to *save* the managed object context. That writes the changes to the backing store (the SQLite file normally) so that they persist.